# Is it possible to specify package name dynamically during build?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'd like to deploy both Debug and Release builds to my device at the same time. I can do this if I manually change the package name in the manifest before I build, e.g. change

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="my.package">
```

to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="my.packageDEBUG">
```

However, I'd like to do this automatically when I'm building the solution. If I do a Debug build, it'll build with `package="my.packageDEBUG"` in the manifest.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom Pre-Build Event for your project.

Right-click on your project and select Properties...

Then click on Build Events and add this to the Pre-build event textbox:

```
PowerShell -File "$(SolutionDir)Update-PackageName.ps1" $(ProjectDir) $(ConfigurationName)
```

Copy the following PowerShell script and save it in your solution folder as *Update-PackageName.ps1*

```
param ([string] $ProjectDir, [string] $ConfigurationName)
Write-Host "ProjectDir: $ProjectDir"
Write-Host "ConfigurationName: $ConfigurationName"

$ManifestPath = $ProjectDir + "Properties\AndroidManifest.xml"

Write-Host "ManifestPath: $ManifestPath"

[xml] $xdoc = Get-Content $ManifestPath

$package = $xdoc.manifest.package

If ($ConfigurationName -eq "Release" -and $package.EndsWith("DEBUG")) 
{ 
    $package = $package.Replace("DEBUG", "") 
}
If ($ConfigurationName -eq "Debug" -and -not $package.EndsWith("DEBUG")) 
{ 
    $package = $package + "DEBUG" 
}

If ($package -ne $xdoc.manifest.package) 
{
    $xdoc.manifest.package = $package
    $xdoc.Save($ManifestPath)
    Write-Host "AndroidManifest.xml package name updated to $package"
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It works! It should be noted that PowerShell requires `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` to be applied before this will work.

Comment: I had to do this in PowerShell: "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser"

Comment: Anybody has any idea how to change the app label (app name) by using a variation of this powershell?

Comment: I know this is an older solution, but when I do this now I get "AndroidManifest does not exist" build error after it does the rename.

Comment: DId you check the Properties folder to see if it exists? If not, have you tried calling the PowerShell script directly to see what it is doing?

Comment: For anyone wondering how to update the app label, and to answer @GustavoBaiocchiCosta - to set the android:label attribute, just retrieve it like $label = $xdoc.manifest.application.label and then do the reverse to update it like $xdoc.manifest.application.label = $label. Fortunately the  android: is preserved by the xml framework and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25127/changing-the-package-name-depending-on-the-build-configuration) on Xamarin's forum you can change the Packaging Properties and specify different `AndroidManifest.xml` files for each build.

In the `droid.csproj` file add the `<AndroidManifest>` tag like so, for each build configuration:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifestDbg.xml</AndroidManifest>
    ...
```

Here's the [Xamarin's documentation on it](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/building-apps/build-process/#Packaging_Properties).

Comment: Did you remove the android manifest tag from the global/outside the property group?

Comment: good one. but with this option you have to manage at least 2 versions of the manifest. Is there a way to merge thos manifest and only overwrite the differences?