# Xamarin.Android change app package name dynamically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i want to change the package name for Android project dynamically related to selected configuration in Visual Studio.

For example, if i want to have same app twice in Google Play Store, one with postfix *full* and one with postfix *free*. So i want to have one configuration for *release full* and one for *release free*, without changing the package name manually each time i select a configuration.
A more complex scenario could include also changing app icon and app name.

Is there a smart way to do this? Maybe a Nuget plugin?

Best regards,
Moritz.

Comment: Worth looking at if creating new build configurations would be the best way to go -> https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/

Comment: Thank you, but a new configuration will not help here, because you can not set a specific configuration or platform in the Android Options page. This page seems to global for all Android configuration.

Comment: I found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47020943/4548007 The drawback here is, that you habe to manage at least 2 different versions of a manifest. The default one and your specific one. The solution here would be some kind of merging boths manifest and only overwrite the differences between them.